# Need Powershell to make a csv of all recipients of all dynamic distribution lists

Tags: powershell, dynamic

I know that the following works to get the names of all people in a single dynamic distribution list:

```
$lister = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "atlanta-members@incose.net"
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter ($lister.RecipientFilter)
```

But I'm not good enough at Powershell to make this into a loop that gives me a csv with the recipients for all lists, with user principal name and the dynamic distribution list name e.g.

````
'memlist', 'hal.jordan@dreamteam.com'
'memlist', 'clark.kent@dreamteam.com'
'otherlist', 'hal.jordan@dreamteam.com'
'otherlist', 'tony.stark@dreamteam.com' ```
````

I'm thinking it's something like:

```
$dynlists = get-dynamicdistributiongroup
ForEach ($dynlist in $dynlists)
{ # Get Dyn list members
     $lister = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity $dynlist | Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter ($lister.RecipientFilter)}
```

but then I got lost on how to get it all into a csv.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```bash
Get-DynamicDistributionGroup | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($recipient in Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $_.RecipientFilter) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            DistributionGroup = $_.Name
            Recipient         = $recipient.Name
            RecipientType     = $recipient.RecipientType
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv the\path\to\theCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```